# A bit odd downvotes resulting in +7 rep while stating -4?

Tags: support

It seems yesterday I've received 2 strange downvotes on my questions:

[image: Downvotes]

What I found strange about it was that they both happened at the exact same time. Seems a bit to much of a coincidence to me. But ok, it's just 4 rep, nothing to worrie about.

But then my Recent achievements showed me "+7 rep", while clicking on it only showed me the -4 rep. So what's going on? Did the strange downvotes get corrected (even though they're still on the questions mentioned)? And if so, how come I'm receiving more than I've lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gained some rep and lost some rep; you just hadn't looked at that info in your profile in a while, so it showed the net from several days.

Here's a screenshot of your profile's reputation tab:

[image: screenshot]

You gained 11 and lost 4. `11 - 4 = +7`.

You may be wondering how you got that +6 on Feb. 17. Well, I can't say for sure because I can't see your votes (no one can). But it's nearly certain that what happened is this: you downvoted an answer on some other day, and that answer was deleted on Feb. 17. You got back your -1 from the downvote. Add that to your upvote and you get +6.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how they would have earned 11 points since they last checked. Your screenshot show `10 - 4 = 6`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I added an explanation of the +6 that went into the +11.

Comment: Well that explains it. Except that when I check my profile, it only shows 5 on Feb 17, haha

Comment: @icecub That's probably a bug. That or it's some weird difference in how mods and other users see things, but I don't have an explanation for that.

Comment: @EdCottrell No seeing 5 on both. Can screenshot it if you want. But not sure if it's something important for you guys

Comment: @EdCottrell No problem. I'm just glad that I know how it happened. Perhaps users simply don't see downvote corrections or it's set to only be visible at a higher rep. Either way, mistery solved! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @icecub do you have the "show removed posts" ticked on your reputation page?

Comment: @TZHX No I didn't. That solved it indeed. Thanks for the tip